# shutdown order in AWS auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to know how can I choose which instance to shut down in an AWS auto scaling group. In my experiments they are killed in FILO order. But I noticed it would cost me less if I used FIFO policy.

Here is an example:

- 0h00: set desired instances to 1. Instance A is started
- 0h10: set desired instances to 2. Instance B is created
- 1h00: set desired instances to 1. Instance B is shut down (50 min uptime => billed a full hour)
- 1h10: set desired instances to 0. Instance A is shut down (1h10 uptime => billed two full hours)

If A and B were shut down in reverse order I would have been billed only 2 hours instead of 3.

Does anyone knows how to overcome this ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, auto scaling groups have a termination policy. You get can more information about your options here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I could find it.